# showButtonPanel property of datepicker is not working after pjax in yii

Tags: gridview, yii, pjax

I am new in Yii. I have added a class on which I am loading a date picker which have showButtonPanel property and it works well, but when I click on reset grid or when pjax code runs then datepicker  works well but somehow buttons on datepicker are not visible or showButtonPanel property doesn't work. Here is a code for this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    callDatePickers();
});

function callDatePickers() {
    $('.anyDayDatePicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        pickTime: false,
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        showButtonPanel : true,
        closeText: 'Clear',
        onClose: function () {
            var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
            if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }
    }).focus(function (input ) {
        console.log("Hello");
        $(input).datepicker('widget').find('.ui-datepicker-current').hide();
        $('.ui-datepicker-close').addClass('clear-date-btn');
    });
}
```

and in index.php

```
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false, 'id' => 'ictmsTrialEventFrom', 'formSelector' => '#ictms-search-form']); ?>

<?=
    GridView::widget([
        'id' => 'crud-datatable',
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
         'filterModel' => $searchModel,
          'pjax' => false,
          'columns' => require(__DIR__ . '/_columns.php'),
     ])       
 ?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>
```

**columns.php**

```
[
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\DataColumn',
        'attribute' => 'actual_date',
        'width' => '15%',
        'value' => function($model) {
            if (isset($model['actual_date'])) {
                return date(Yii::$app->params['dateFormat'], strtotime($model['actual_date']));
            }
        },
        'filter' => \yii\jui\DatePicker::widget([
            'model' => $searchModel,
            'attribute' => 'actual_date',
            'language' => 'ru',
            'dateFormat' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
            'options' => ['class' => 'anyDayDatePicker'],
        ]),
    ],
```

Can anybody give me solution why showButtonPanel not working after pjax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You should rather call your script on [`pjax:end`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events) event so that whenever the PJAX load/reload finishes replacing content to the page your script is called

So replace the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    callDatePickers();
});
```

with the following

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:end', function(event) {
  callDatePickers();
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but on pjax end I am able to get alert but still showButtonPanel is not working

Comment: @Amarja **not working** does not help much can you explain what you are experiencing any errors when you click on the button